# Error in if (is.double(data$x) && !has_groups(data) && any(data$x != data$x[1L])) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm trying to use ggplot, and am hoping to create a boxplot that has four categories on the x axis for suspension data (low, lowish, highish, high) and farms on the y-axis.

I have *I think* broken the suspension column into four groups. But ggplot is upset with me. Here is the error:

````
```
Error in if (is.double(data$x) && !has_groups(data) && any(data$x != data$x[1L])) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```
````

Here is my code:

````
```{r}
# To break suspension_rate_total_pct data into groups for clearer visualization, I found the min, and max
merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct)
max(merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct, na.rm=TRUE)
min(merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct, na.rm=TRUE)
low_suspension <- merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct > 0 & merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct < 0.5
low_ish_suspension <- merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct > 0.5 & merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct < 1
high_ish_suspension <- merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct > 1 & merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct < 1.5
high_suspension <- merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct > 1.5 & merged_data$suspension_rate_total_pct < 2

ggplot(merged_data, aes(x = suspension_rate_total_pct , y = farms_pct)) +
        geom_boxplot()
```
````

Here is the Data:

```
    merged_data <- structure(list(schid = c("1030642", "1030766", "1030774", "1030840", 
    "1130103", "1230150"), enrollment = c(159, 333, 352, 430, 102, 
    193), farms = c(132, 116, 348, 406, 68, 130), foster = c(2, 0, 
    1, 8, 1, 4), homeless = c(14, 0, 8, 4, 1, 4), migrant = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ell = c(18, 12, 114, 45, 7, 4), suspension_rate_total = c(NA, 
    20, 0, 0, 95, 5), suspension_violent = c(NA, 9, 0, 0, 20, 2), 
        suspension_violent_no_injury = c(NA, 6, 0, 0, 47, 1), suspension_weapon = c(NA, 
        0, 0, 0, 8, 0), suspension_drug = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1), suspension_defiance = c(NA, 
        1, 0, 0, 9, 1), suspension_other = c(NA, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0), 
        farms_pct = c(0.830188679245283, 0.348348348348348, 0.988636363636364, 
        0.944186046511628, 0.666666666666667, 0.673575129533679), 
        foster_pct = c(0.0125786163522013, 0, 0.00284090909090909, 
        0.0186046511627907, 0.00980392156862745, 0.0207253886010363
        ), migrant_pct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ell_pct = c(0.113207547169811, 
        0.036036036036036, 0.323863636363636, 0.104651162790698, 
        0.0686274509803922, 0.0207253886010363), homeless_pct = c(0.0880503144654088, 
        0, 0.0227272727272727, 0.00930232558139535, 0.00980392156862745, 
        0.0207253886010363), suspension_rate_total_pct = c(NA, 2, 
        1, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If you can, please help me appease ggplot so that it will give me with beautiful visualization. Currently, this feels like a one-sided, emotional rollercoaster of a relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want your plot to look like. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'm hoping to create a boxplot that has four categories on the x axis for suspension data (low, lowish, highis, high) and farms on the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for editing my data! :)

Comment: the problem seems to lie in your group calculation, merged data has NA's in suspension_rate_total_pct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a short answer, i am sure you can figure out the rest by yourself, (otherwise post a followup question.)

Since the data you provided has some NA's in the first row in several columns, i can only demonstrate you the principle on how to get your desired result by using the merged_data$homless value as group-input for our boxplots , the data (y-value) will be still Farms .

```
# first we create our groups of low, middle & high amount of homeless 
merged_data2<- merged_data %>% mutate(homelessgroup= ifelse(homeless < 4, "low",
                                                     ifelse(homeless <= 8, "middle",
                                                     ifelse(homeless > 8, "high",NA ))))

## then we plot the data using ggplot

ggplot(merged_data2,aes(y=farms,fill=homelessgroup))+geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: When I plug in:  # first we create our groups of low, middle & high amount of homeless 
merged_data2<- merged_data %>% mutate(homelessgroup= ifelse(homeless < 4, "low"),
                                                     ifelse(homeless <= 8, "middle"),
                                                     ifelse(homeless > 8, "high",NA))                                     It tells me:                                                                                                                  
 Error in ifelse(homeless < 4, "low") : argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: code works for me - do you have all 4 ) at the end & dont use an ) after "low"; its one bracet open after mutate( and one open after each ifelse( , so total of )))) at the end

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `cut()` with your data to partition into 4 groups. Then you can use that variable with the plot

```
merged_data <- transform(merged_data, 
          group = cut(
            suspension_rate_total_pct, 
            c(0, .5, 1, 1.5, 2), 
            include.lowest = TRUE,
            labels = c("low", "lowish", "highish", "high")))

ggplot(merged_data, aes(x = group , y = farms_pct)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: nice! didnt know about the cut function does it use the range beween each value in vector c ?  0 to 0.5  ->"low" , 0.5 to 1 -> "lowish" , etc?

Comment: Yep. You can find out more on the help page `?cut`. You set breakpoints and then can optionally give those ranges names.

Comment: bro thats hot! i know about help pages (but i usually enter them by F1 insted of ? )